# PostgreSQL query get all entries with many-to-many relationship with another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `posts` which has a many-to-many relationship with `tags`, the pivot table is called `posts-tags`.

I want to be able to retrieve all `posts` by a list of tag id's.

Imagine

```
posts

id | text
--------
1  | "foo"
2  | "bar"
3  | "baz"
```

```
posts_tags

post_id | tag_id
-----------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 1
3       | 1
```

```
tags

id | name
--------
1  | "foo"
2  | "bar"
3  | "baz"
```

With tag id's `[1, 2, 3]`, I should get back `[{id: 1, text: "foo"}]`

With tag id's `[1]`, I should get back `[{id: 1, text: "foo"}, {id: 2, text: "bar"}, {id: 3, text: "baz"}]`

Basically, I want to retrieve all the posts related to the list of tags.

Comment: have you tried using `IN` or `EXISTS` clauses? what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to filter posts that have all the specified tags:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object('id', p.id, 'text', p.txt)) 
from posts p where (select count(*) from json_array_elements('[1, 2, 3]') v 
      join post_tags t on t.post_id = p.id and v.value::text::int = t.tag_id) = json_array_length('[1, 2, 3]')
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3eb11b838c88857762b7319976917f35).